# reached end of file while parsing

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

Descargué un archivo Springboot y ahora ningun otro archivo me sirve, me aparece el mismo error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project tienda: Compilation failure
> com/tienda/ProjectConfig.java:[16,1] reached end of file while parsing
>
> -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
> Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

¿Que hago?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

este error puede deberse a varias razones, como una configuración incorrecta del plugin, una dependencia faltante o una versión de Java incompatible.

Algunas posibles soluciones que puedes intentar son:

- Revisar la configuración del plugin de Maven en tu archivo pom.xml y asegurarte de que especificas la versión correcta de Java para el parámetro source y target. Por ejemplo, si usas Java 11, debes poner `<source>11</source>` y `<target>11</target>`.
- Verificar que tienes instalada la versión de Java que corresponde a la que usas en tu proyecto y que la tienes configurada correctamente en tu IDE y en tu variable de entorno JAVA_HOME.
  Actualizar la versión de Maven a la más reciente y limpiar el caché de Maven.
- Ejecutar el comando mvn -e para ver el detalle del error y buscar posibles causas adicionales.

no conozco la libreria que estas usando pero el error de compilacion que te esta sucediendo dice que en el archivo ProjectConfig.java se te olvido cerrar un bloque de codigo, ya sea parentesis, llaves o punto y coma. como te digo, no se si ese archivo es de la libreria que estas usando porque no conosco la libreria pero si no es de la libreria verifica cuidadozamente que no se te olvido cerrar algun bloque de codigo, y en caso de que sea el archivo  de la libreria puedes intentar hacer lo que te dije.